# Spring Cloud Config: Bootstrap context not loading profile-specific property files for binding

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, apache-syncope, spring-cloud-config-client

## Setup

- Spring Boot 2.6.0
- Spring Cloud Config 3.1 RC1
- Apache Maven 3.8.x
- OpenJDK 11

## Overview

I have a multi-module Apache Maven project that is set up with the following modules:

1. bootstrap: contains a `PropertySourceLocator` for `BootstrapConfiguration`, defined in `spring.factories` file.
2. starter: depends on bootstrap, and it's a (servlet-based) web application
3. reference: deploys the starter application using the Maven Cargo plugin, deploying into an Apache Tomcat 9.0.55

## Runtime

- The starter module declares a configuration class, annotated with `@PropertySource("wa.properties")`. This `wa.properties` on the classpath of the starter module has a setting: `cas.authn.syncope.name=Starter`
- The starter module has a `ServletInitializer` that sets the `spring.config.name` property to "wa" when building the spring application.
- The reference module only has a `wa-embedded.properties` file on the classpath with a setting: `cas.authn.syncope.name=Embedded`
- The reference module starts with the spring activated profiles: `embedded,all`

Note: the `cas.authn.syncope.name` is bound to a Java POJO, `CasConfigurationProperties`, that is annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties("cas")`.

## Observation

The following bean in the application exists, simplified for this post:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "something")
@RefreshScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
public Something something(ApplicationContext ctx, CasConfigurationProperties cas) {
    ...
}
```

- If I look at the contents of `cas.getAuthn().getSyncope().getName())`, it shows: "Starter"
- If I look at `ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("cas.authn.syncope.name")`, it shows "Embedded".

In other words, property binding used during the bootstrapping process does not match the actual environment for the application's context.

## Analysis

- It appears that when the bootstrap application context is created, `wa-embedded.properties`, a profile-specific property is not read. In fact, the only property source that is used for binding is `wa.properties` as part of "localProperties", which I believe comes from `@PropertySource("wa.properties")`. Nothing else is read or found.
- Then, property binding takes place binding `CasConfigurationProperties` and `cas.authn.syncope.name` initialized from `@PropertySource("wa.properties")`. The value of this property is set to `Starter`.
- Then, the application servlet context is initialized and its environment is post-processed with profiles and the appropriate listener and Spring beans are created. In particular, this bean:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "something")
@RefreshScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
public Something something(ApplicationContext ctx, CasConfigurationProperties cas) {
    ...
}
```

...shows that `ctx` is the actual application context with an environment that is post-processed via all profiles and shows `ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("cas.authn.syncope.name")` as "Embedded".

However, `CasConfigurationProperties` was processed using the Bootstrap context only, and its equivalent property shows "Starter".

...which means the bean would be created using the wrong values in `CasConfigurationProperties`.

## Research

This setup works OK using Spring Boot 2.5.6 and Spring Cloud 3.0.5. I don't think anything in Spring Boot has changed that would affect this, but I do see a number of differences in Cloud between 3.0 and 3.1.

I am not sure I can create a reproducer to adequately showcase this. I'll try. In the meantime, could you evaluate this and see if this might be seen as a bug, or misconfiguration of some kind?